# How to make html5 pattern for allow numbers and dash any where between them

Tags: regex, html

I want to allow only number and a dash between them anywhere.
Can anybody share your ideas please!
I tried Some but doesn't work for me...
/^[0-9-]+$/
 \d+[-]+\d\,[0-9]+

Comment: Is this what you want: `^\d+-\d+$`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you tried multiple regexes.

This `^[0-9-]+$`  will match digits and dashes but will also match `---5555` because you add them in a character set and repeat them.

This `\d+[-]+\d` would match one or more digits, a single dash and then 1 digit.

This `[0-9]+` would match only digits.

To allow only digits and a dash between them anywhere you could use:

[`^\d+(?:-\d+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/WgRXMo/1)

**This will match**

```
^     # From the beginning of the string
\d+   # match one or more digits
(?:   # A non capturing group
 -\d+ # Match a dash and one or more digits
)*    # Close non capturing group and repeat zero or more times
$     # The end of the string
```

To will allow only single digits with a dash, you could use [`^\d(?:-\d)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/WgRXMo/2).

These will not match a dash at the beginning or at the end, only between digits.

To have at least 1 dash you repeat the non capturing group one or more times using a `+` instead of `*` which will match zero or more times.

Comment: yahhh its works Thank You so much you have solved my problem